# React Native Navigator kept component will be polluted of redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am using react-redux for React Native project.
React Native Navigator will keep old components in stack but just to hide components from screen.
In the mean time, if current scene uses the same state.propName, the hidden scenes will be changed as well.
While navigator.pop() to old scene, the UI was being changed.

For example,
I have two scenes `<PostList>` and `<ImagePostList>` and the redux `state.posts` stores the posts data list.

In `<PostList>`, state.posts stores all kind of posts (including image posts).

In `<ImagePostList>`, state.posts stores just image posts.

When I `navigator.push()` from `<PostList>` to `<ImagePostList>`, I will grab new post list by action/reducer and save to state.posts.

Then I do `navigator.pop()` back to original `<PostList>`, the state.posts now only have image posts since it was being override.

I did some trace for react-router/redux-router, it seems they don't have such issues because in web components will be unmounted/remounted between routes.

One possible solution is to save the original component state when pushing to new scene.  While pop back, use the data from our component state instead using props from react-redux.
But the solution will increase a lot of complexity since the data right now does not come from single truth.

Another possible solution is simply to isolate the state.propName from all routes. But I think it is not a good idea right now.

Anyone who ever faced such problems, please be kindly to share your experience with me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally turn to use a stack to store state between navigation change.
Since I use redux actions to control navigator (i.e. push to route or pop from route), it is simple to do it by a reducer-enhancer.

The mechanism is pretty like [redux-undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo), but I wrote a simpler one.

```js
const ActionTypes = {
  PUSH_ROUTE: 'PUSH_ROUTE',
  POP_ROUTE: 'POP_ROUTE'
};

export default function navAwarable(reducer) {
  var stateStack = [];
  return (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === PUSH_ROUTE) {
      stateStack.push(state);
      return reducer(state, action);
    } else if (action.type === POP_ROUTE) {
      let origState = stateStack.pop();
      return reducer(origState, action);
    } else {
      return reducer(state, action);
    }
  };
};
```

And usage

```js
export default combineReducers({
  route,
  posts: navAwarable(posts)
});
```